# Save code before running android emulator?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-emulator

Do I need to save before running the android emulator on eclipse.

I get the error `MainActivity.java has been modified. Save changes?`

Can I not save?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you were to run without saving, your new code would not be compiled and the emulator would not run the code you had just typed. If you are not sure about a change or want to keep older versions, just use the Save As command and keep multiple versions.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is Yes, as ADT would check up the changes in the code, else the previous non updated code would be executed. There will be also a case where you have rectified a problem in your project and you will be still be facing it in the execution if the project is not saved.

Comment: Thanks, So if i save the codes, would there be anyway to ctrl-z to get back the old codes?

Answer (score 0):

You're answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12546606/how-to-run-a-simple-java-program-in-eclipse)

The answer, is yes. Yes, you have to save it.

Comment: what part of the linked question provides an answer to OP's question?

Comment: The part that talks about running the program. Is this not a duplicate, @panini?